# Calculating the average with NA

Tags: r

Let’s say we have two numerical variables x1 and x2. Some rows have missing values for x1, or x2, or both. I need to create a third variable, say ave,  to calculate the average of x1 and x1 if both exist (ave=mean(x1,x2)); if only one of them exist, then ave= xi, i = 1 or 2. If both are missing, then ave=NA.

Here is what I have

```
df <- data.frame(x1=c(1,2,3,3,NA,5,6,2,6,NA,1,2,6, NA), x2=c(4,2,8,NA,NA,5,6,2,NA,3,1,2,6, NA))


    x1  x2
1   1   4
2   2   2
3   3   8
4   3   NA
5   NA  NA
6   5   5
7   6   6
8   2   2
9   6   NA
10  NA  3
11  1   1
12  2   2
13  6   6
14  NA  NA
```

What I need

```
    x1  x2  ave
1   1   4   2.5
2   2   2   2
3   3   8   11.5
4   3   NA  3
5   NA  NA  NA
6   5   5   5
7   6   6   6
8   2   2   2
9   6   NA  6
10  NA  3   3
11  1   1   1
12  2   2   2
13  6   6   6
14  NA  NA  NA
```

Comment: `df$ave = rowMeans(df, na.rm=TRUE)`

Comment: how can i use mean(x1,x2) instead of rowMeans? as i've other variables in df. Thanks

Comment: `df$ave = rowMeans(df[, c("x1","x2")], na.rm=TRUE)`

Comment: @eipi10, that should be the accepted answer (although it must be a duplicate..)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put your rules in ifelse statement:

```
> df$ave = with(df, ifelse(is.na(x1), x2, ifelse(is.na(x2), x1,(x1+x2)/2)))
> 
> df
   x1 x2 ave
1   1  4 2.5
2   2  2 2.0
3   3  8 5.5
4   3 NA 3.0
5  NA NA  NA
6   5  5 5.0
7   6  6 6.0
8   2  2 2.0
9   6 NA 6.0
10 NA  3 3.0
11  1  1 1.0
12  2  2 2.0
13  6  6 6.0
14 NA NA  NA
```